# Runtime.getRuntime.exec() does not work properly

Tags: java, linux

Im trying to run a javac command using Runtime.getRuntime.exec(); 
The Command itself runs just fine when i paste it into my bash, but some reason it doesnt work when executing it from within my program.

**Command**

```
javac -cp $(find '/root/discobo/libs' -type f -printf '%p:') -sourcepath '/root/discobo/git/Bot/src' $(find '/root/discobo/git/Bot/src' -name '*.java') -d '/root/discobo/target' -Xlint:all
```

I've already tried using javas ProcessBuilder which sadly gave me the same results.

It gives me the following **error**

> javac: invalid flag: '/root/discobo/libs/'

This makes no sense me to since the command works just fine from the bash.

I hope someone has a solution for this :) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **find** command which is only understood by bash. So if you execute this on bash, bash expands or replaces **$(find)** with actual result i.e. the files and then **javac** is invoked with actual files list.

So while executing the same using Runtime.getRuntime.exec() use as

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("bash -c \"javac -cp $(find '/root/discobo/libs' -type f -printf '%p:') -sourcepath '/root/discobo/git/Bot/src' $(find '/root/discobo/git/Bot/src' -name '*.java') -d '/root/discobo/target' -Xlint:all\"")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It’s not so much *`find`* as `$(…)`. And it’s not so much *Bash* as any POSIXy shell.

Comment: Works like a charm :) thanks